# SQL cumulative sum

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

[image]

From this, I would like for each market to find the names of the product that has brought the company the most cumulative sales (as measured by InvoicePrice).

I tried the following in mysql :

```
create table Contacts (
    CustomerID integer primary key,
    FullName text,
    MarketID text
);

create table Order_ (
    OrderID integer primary key,
    CustomerID integer,
    OrderDate date,
    foreign key (CustomerID) references Contacts(CustomerID)
);

create table Product (
    ProductCode integer primary key,
    Brand text,
    ProductName text
);

create table OrderedItems (
    OrderedItemID integer primary key,
    OrderID integer not NULL,
    ProductCode integer not NULL,
    InvoicePrice integer,
    foreign key (ProductCode) references Product(ProductCode),
    foreign key (OrderID) references Order_(OrderID)
);

insert into Contacts values(1, "John", "MarketA");
insert into Contacts values(2, "Jack", "MarketA");
insert into Contacts values(3, "George", "MarketB");
insert into Contacts values(4, "Karen", "MarketC");
insert into Contacts values(5, "Lucy", "MarketB");

insert into Product values(1, "Western Digital", "Hard drive 1TB");
insert into Product values(2, "Samsung", "Monitor 27");
insert into Product values(3, "nVidia", "GPU 8GB");

insert into Order_ values(1, 1, "2020-1-1"); -- John's
insert into Order_ values(2, 1, "2020-1-2"); -- John's
insert into Order_ values(3, 1, "2021-1-2"); -- John's
insert into Order_ values(4, 5, "2020-1-1"); -- Lucy's
insert into Order_ values(5, 4, "2020-1-1"); -- Karen's

insert into OrderedItems values(1, 1, 1, 1000); -- John's 1st order, 1st item
insert into OrderedItems values(2, 1, 1, 1000); -- John's 1st order, 2nd item
insert into OrderedItems values(3, 2, 2, 300); -- John's 2nd order, 1st item
insert into OrderedItems values(4, 4, 1, 1000); -- Lucy's 1st order, 1st item

select Contacts.MarketID, Y.ProductName, sum(Y.Price) as TotalSales
    from (
        select T.ProductName as ProductName, T.Price as Price, Order_.CustomerID as CustomerID 
            from (
                select Product.ProductName as ProductName, OrderedItems.OrderID as OrderID, OrderedItems.InvoicePrice as Price 
                from Product join OrderedItems on OrderedItems.ProductCode = Product.ProductCode
            ) as T
            join Order_ on Order_.OrderID = T.OrderID
    ) as Y
    join Contacts on Contacts.CustomerID = Y.CustomerID
    group by Contacts.MarketID, Y.ProductName
;
```

I get this output...

| MarketID | ProductName | TotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MarketA | Hard drive 1TB | 2000 |
| MarketB | Hard drive 1TB | 1000 |
| MarketA | Monitor 27 | 300 |

But I would like to get this output (Since Hard drive 1TB has more cumulative sales in Market A)...

| MarketID | ProductName | TotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MarketA | Hard drive 1TB | 2000 |
| MarketB | Hard drive 1TB | 1000 |

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @J.D. I am using this online editor https://paiza.io/projects/eIeqzRtKckNr_AsptMg0Ww?language=mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranking your TotalSales by Market and then selecting back rows where rank is 1 should help you get what you’re looking for.

```
select MarketId,
    ProductName,
    TotalSales
from
    (
    select Contacts.MarketID,
        Y.ProductName,
        sum(Y.Price) as TotalSales,
        rank() over ( partition by Contacts.MarketID order by sum(Y.Price) desc ) as "sale_rank"
    from (
        select T.ProductName as ProductName,
            T.Price as Price,
            Order_.CustomerID as CustomerID 
        from (
            select Product.ProductName as ProductName,
                OrderedItems.OrderID as OrderID,
                OrderedItems.InvoicePrice as Price 
            from Product
            join OrderedItems on OrderedItems.ProductCode = Product.ProductCode
            ) as T
        join Order_ on Order_.OrderID = T.OrderID
    ) as Y
    join Contacts on Contacts.CustomerID = Y.CustomerID
    group by Contacts.MarketID,
        Y.ProductName
) as s
where s.sale_rank = 1
```

| MarketId | ProductName | TotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MarketA | Hard drive 1TB | 2000 |
| MarketB | Hard drive 1TB | 1000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9efb15c2a16ac2fdc2617dcb930f7b7)

Comment: is it possible to add another question or should I create a new post?

Comment: If you’re seeking additional clarity on the answer, feel free to ask it here, and I’ll update the answer to cover it. If it’s unrelated to the original question/answer, I’d suggest you start a new post.